# Pre-configure TightVNC as (reverse connection) listener (service)?

Tags: vnc, tightvnc

Is it possible to pre-config my TightVNC service and let it act as (reverse connection) listener for a certain host, without doing this via the GUI?

I've been roaming through many websites, looking for answers, have checked the Windows registry a dozen of times in various locations, but am unable to find anything related to TightVNC's "Attach Listening Viewer", which is accessible in the service config application, via the systray context menu.

I did find something else but i'm not sure if it's the thing i'm looking for. Heck, i have no clue what it does:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run]

"tvncontrol"="\"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\TightVNC\\tvnserver.exe\" -controlservice -slave"
```

Thank you in advance, Superusers! ;-)

**edit:** Okay... i'm a bit embarrassed to say this but i believe i've found it.

http://www.tightvnc.com/docs.php

How to configure TightVNC Server via the command line:

• [TightVNC for Windows: Server Command-Line Options (PDF)](http://www.tightvnc.com/doc/win/TightVNC_2.7_for_Windows_Server_Command-Line_Options.pdf)

It covers all (except the **-slave**) command line options and their usage/purpose.

If someone knows what the undocumented `-slave` parameter is for, leave a comment ;-)

**Well..**, i can't seem to get the listener mode to work. Whatever i do, tvnserver.exe either keeps showing me the command-line usage options or shows nothing at all.

I did everything by the manual and tried the following:
`tvnserver.exe -controlservice -connect xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` (masked IP-address)

**Hmm**, i've finally managed to make it work. All i had to do was keeping tvnviewer.exe enabled as listener. I was under the impression that the server would contineaously attempt to connect, but this wasn't the case.

**I conclude this journey with a final question:**

Since both the server and the viewer (client) have a listener option, under what circumstances am i supposed to put the TightVNC **viewer** in listening mode, and when should this be done for the **server**?

Best regards,

**/copyitright**

Comment: According to the [instruction (in Russian)](http://www.smeegul.kiev.ua/vnc.html) it is enough to start `vncviewer.exe -listen 5432`, and then use command `Attach Listening Viewer...` in VNC-server's menu to establish the reverse connection. I'm not sure whether same functionality is available in command line. Here is similar [instruction in English](https://verahill.blogspot.com/2012/02/debian-testing-wheezy-64-reverse-vnc.html).

Answer (score 1):

found the answer here:

https://kempniu.wordpress.com/2009/03/21/reverse-connections-in-tightvnc/

on hostA run `vncviewer -listen`

on hostB run:  `WinVNC.exe -connect hostA_address::5500`

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1132688)